# restoreCompletedTransactions and asking to login

Tags: ios, xcode, storekit

It's my first integration of In-App Purchases. I have everything working: I can buy the item I want, also use [`restoreCompletedTransactions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions).

Every time I call `restoreCompletedTransactions()` I am asked for username and password.

Is this because I am in sandbox mode or will this happen once being live as well?
How do I check if the user has bought it before? (I know I can save it in the user settings, but it would be nice to check if it was bought by polling the Apple server without the user needing to enter username and password).

How do others handle this? Because surely you want to know if they refunded it.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: nope... still waiting for someone to answer. Just to be able to launch the app I don't do the check, but have a "restore purchase" button in the settings page. Doesn't provide the check i wanted though

Comment: The way to deal with this is handled on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757467/when-to-use-restorecompletedtransactions-for-in-app-purchases

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the [Apple Article](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9) Instructions on how "not" to do this:

> Restoring purchases prompts for the user’s App Store credentials, which interrupts the flow of your app: because of this, don’t automatically restore purchases, especially not every time your app is launched.

The best way to do this would be use receipts.

Steps in general are:

1) Your app would usually request a payment upon first time use

2) Once the customer has paid (or subscribed), then

3) Your app should download the receipt from the AppStore, and then store a copy of the Private Key and certificate details onto your server (or Cloud if it's a non-renewable subscription)

4) Your server should verify that receipt with the AppStore.

5) Optional: Your server can then query-last-receipt to ensure that the user's subscription is always up to date.

6) Once your server is satisfied, then let the app know that content can now be unlocked etc.

In other words, use receipts to verify and not keep retrieving finished transactions otherwise it would put your customers off by keep asking them for the iTunes password every time they need to start your app.

For more information, please watch this [apple video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/308/)

I hope this helps

Regards

Heider